# Size of MPI_Aint?

Tags: c, mpi

I have a simple question about `MPI_Aint`, but I didn't find any answer anywhere. For some reason, `MPI_Type_size(MPI_Aint)` doesn't work (it does not look like classical datatypes, e.g. `MPI_Double` or `MPI_Int`), at least with OpenMPI 1.8.4 and 1.10.1 but I don't think it's an OpenMPI problem.

I have to create a type with `MPI_Type_create_hindexed()` and to allocate the `array_of_displacements` array dynamically. After computing a size `N`, I wrote

```
MPI_Aint* disps = (MPI_Aint*) malloc(N*sizeof(MPI_Aint)) ;
```

instead of

```
int mpiAintSize ;
MPI_Type_size(MPI_Aint, &mpiAintSize) ;
MPI_Aint* disps = (MPI_Aint*) malloc(N*mpiAintSize) ;
```

because of this problem. sizeof() will do the job as long as I'm lucky and I don't need portability (this array will be used to write/read big files with MPI-I/O).

But I would like to know: what is the clean and portable way to allocate my `disps` array ? What did I miss about MPI_Aint ?

Comment: EDIT: For anybody interested, I figured out after Gilles' reply that there is no portability problem with `MPI_Aint` being a C type. We never read/write `MPI_Aint`s, and we only use their value to define the structure (which does not depend on their size in memory). Hence no need to create a uniform (portable) `MPI_Type` for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MPI_Aint` isn't a `MPI_Type` such as `MPI_INT`, `MPI_DOUBLE` or what you create with `MPI_Type_create_hindexed()`, `MPI_Aint` is a type in the C language, like `int`, `double` or a `struct`. In fact I suspect that most of the time `MPI_Aint` will simply be define as a `typedef` large enough to store what it needs to. Most probably, it will be define as either `typedef long MPI_Aint;` or `typedef long long MPI_Aint;`.

Therefore, your approach for allocating your array is correct in using `sizeof()` instead of `MPI_Type_size()`.

Comment: Indeed, after checking I found the typedef in my mpi.h, it comes as a ptrdiff_t... IMHO it is quite confusing to have `MPI_Double` look like `MPI_Aint` whereas one is a `MPI_type`but not the other. But anyway, thank you very much for your answer !

Comment: @RobinHuart If I understand correctly and for more confusion there is even a `MPI_AINT` datatype that describes an `MPI_Aint`. https://trac.mpich.org/projects/mpich/browser/src/include/mpi.h.in?rev=fd6627a1bf6cdbe629defe77db231558948c48dd